# Reading a line in a BufReader creates an infinite loop

Tags: rust, server, tcp, network-programming

I'm trying to receive a message (server side) on the network using TcpListener in Rust.
Here's the server code:

```
// Instanciate TcpListener
let server = TcpListener::bind("0.0.0.0:52001").expect("Could not bind");

match server.accept() { // Waiting new connection from a client
    Ok((stream, addr)) => { 
        println!("New connection from {}", addr);

        // Wrapping the stream in a BufReader
        let mut reader = BufReader::new(&stream); 
        let mut message = String::new();

        loop { // Entering the loop when a client is connected
            reader.read_line(&mut message).expect("Cannot read new line");
            println!("message received: {}", message);
            message.clear();
        }
    }
    Err(e) => {
        println!("Fail: {:?}", e)
    }
}
```

Here's my Kotlin client:

```
Socket("192.168.134.138", 52001).use { client ->
    client.getOutputStream().use { out ->
        out.write("test\n".toByteArray())
    }
}
while(true) {
    Thread.sleep(15_000)
}
```

The client send the following line: `test\n` and it ends with a linebreak for the server to read.

The intended behaviours would be that on the server side it prints `message received: test` and then the server waits at the `read_line()` instruction for the next line

It works because I receive the `test` but the `read_line()` method does not seem to block nor wait for another message. So it creates an infinite loop. So in the terminal I'm getting:

```
New connection from 192.168.134.123:7869    
message received: test
message received:
message received:
message received:
message received:

Process finished with exit code 130 (interrupted by signal 2: SIGINT)
```

And I have to stop the program forcefully.

Any ideas?

Comment: I already cut the code that was not necessary so I think it is as minimal as I can. The client is in Kotlin so I'm not sure if it is relevant to post the code here. I'll still update my post to include more information as you say

Comment: Check the result of `read_line`. If it returns `Ok(0)`, that indicates EOF has been reached so you can break out of the loop.

Comment: Incidentally, this has nothing to do with your question, but it might still be helpful to you: currently, you create a new `String` at each iteration of the loop. Instead, you could create a single `String` outside, and call `message.clear()` at the end of each iteration, which is more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect the end of the stream, you need to check if `read_line()` returned `Ok(0)`:

From the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.read_line):

> If this function returns `Ok(0)`, the stream has reached EOF.

```rust
loop { // Entering the loop when a client is connected
    let mut message = String::new();
    if reader.read_line(&mut message).expect("Cannot read new line") == 0 {
        break;
    }
    println!("message received: {}", message);
}
```

Another way option is to use `BufReader::lines()` iterator:

```rust
for line in reader.lines() {
    let message = line.expect("Cannot read new line");
    println!("message received: {}", message);
}
```

This approach is a bit inefficient as it allocates a new String on every iteration. For best performance, you should allocate a single String and reuse it like @BlackBeans pointed out in a comment:

```rust
let mut message = String::new();
loop { // Entering the loop when a client is connected
    message.clear();
    if reader.read_line(&mut message).expect("Cannot read new line") == 0 {
        break;
    }
    println!("message received: {}", message);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The proposition using `reader.lines()` is better I think but was not fixing my problem. While I was trying to respond I became aware that the client was closing the connection (the `use` method is closing the stream). That was the reason why `read_line` was not blocking as I was expecting and in fact using `dbg!()` I saw the EOF like you said.